# Integrating Docker into the existing TFS-based infrastructure (not web-apps)

Tags: python, docker, tfs, continuous-integration

I need some general advice here. In our (large) company we have an already established test and build infrastructure that is based on MS TFS to build and test our products. Quick facts:

- mostly C++ and C# code
- system-level software
- relying on lots of pre-configured build agents
- supported by folks with TFS expertise

For a new Python project (which is not a web-app either) we need to set up a CI. My idea is to piggy-back on the existing unified infrastructure and take advantage of Docker container. Here is my idea: on every check-in into Python project's repository launch a dedicated TFS build which

- pulls the code
- builds a Docker container or image
- runs the tests inside it
- and...?

And here is the question: what is the best way to interact with the outside world? How would you advice to push results out if we're not planning to build a web-app? Ideally I would like to keep only the failed tests' artifacts while not even keeping all those containers from every check-in.